# What is the difference between two ticker symbols for the same company?

Tags: equities

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XOMAP/profile?p=XOMAP
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XOMAO/profile?p=XOMAO

Both of the above two ticker symbols are for the same company (XOMA Corporation). It is not clear what their differences are. Could anybody show me what their differences are?

Answer (score 3):

One is [preferred stock](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/preferredstock.asp) and the other is not. I don't know the specifics of XOMA.

The key takeaways on the linked page are not entirely correct. These are all things that might be true but are not necessarily the case. Some of them will apply though.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @BobJansen's answer, I found this information:

- **XOMAP** is the ticker for the [Series A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_A_round) preferred shares of the corporation. Aka the first round of capital financing the corporation did.
- **XOMAO** is the ticker for the company's depository shares representing 1/1000th fractional interest in a share of the company's Series B Cumulative [Perpetual Preferred stock](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/perpetual-preferred-stock.asp) (*see also [this link](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cumulative_preferred_stock.asp) for the definition of the cumulative perpetual preferred stock*). The above information and more about the certain conditions applied to these depository shares are found from [this announcement](https://www.globenewswire.com/en/news-release/2021/04/05/2204533/7281/en/XOMA-Announces-Offering-of-Depositary-Shares-and-Series-B-Cumulative-Perpetual-Preferred-Stock.html).